# ¿como asignar una key a un array dentro de otro array?

Tags: php

Buenas tengo este codigo en mi controlador (es en mvc).

```
function actualizar_formato_valuaciones()
    {
         $id = $_POST['id'];
         $antes = $_POST['antes'];
       // echo $id;
        //print_r($id);
        print_r(implode(',',(array)$_POST['data']));

            $data = implode(',',(array)$_POST['data']);

            $data = str_replace("[","",$data);
            $data = str_replace("]","",$data);
            $data = str_replace("\"", "'", $data); 

            $comentarios = array(
                'form_obser_1' => $_POST['observaciones1'], 
                'form_obser_2' => $_POST['observaciones2'],
                'form_obser_3' => $_POST['observaciones3'],
                'form_obser_4' => $_POST['observaciones4'],
                'form_obser_5' => $_POST['observaciones5'],
                'form_obser_6' => $_POST['observaciones6'],
                'form_obser_7' => $_POST['observaciones7'],
                'form_obser_8' => $_POST['observaciones8'],
                'form_obser_9' => $_POST['observaciones9'],
                'form_obser_10' => $_POST['observaciones10'],
                'form_area_1' => $_POST['check1'],
                'form_area_2' => $_POST['check2'],
                'form_area_3' => $_POST['check3'],
                'form_area_4' => $_POST['check4'],
                'form_area_5' => $_POST['check5'],
                'form_area_6' => $_POST['check6'],
                'form_area_7' => $_POST['check7'],
                'form_area_8' => $_POST['check8'],
                'form_area_9' => $_POST['check9'],
                'form_area_10' => $_POST['check10'],
                'form_area_11' => $_POST['check11'],
                'form_area_12' => $_POST['check12'],
                'form_area_13' => $_POST['check13'],
                'form_area_14' => $_POST['check14'],
                'form_area_15' => $_POST['check15'],
                'form_area_16' => $_POST['check16'],
                'form_area_17' => $_POST['check17'],
                'form_area_18' => $_POST['check18'],
                'form_area_19' => $_POST['check19'],
                'form_area_20' => $_POST['check20'],
                'form_area_21' => $_POST['check21'],
                'form_area_22' => $_POST['check22'],
                'form_area_23' => $_POST['check23'],
                'form_area_24' => $_POST['check24']

        ); 

            $data2 = array_push($data,$comentarios);


            $updata = array(
            "fecha_cot_av" => date('Y-m-d'),
            "cliente_cot_av" => $_POST['clientec'],
            "tec_id_cot_av" => $_POST['tecnicoc'],
            "unidad_cot_av" => $_POST['unidadc'],
            "ven_id_cot_av" => $_POST['vendedorc'],
            "serie_cot_av" => $_POST['seriec'],
            "km_cot_av" => $_POST['kilometrajec'],
            "des_trab_cot_av1" => $_POST['descripcion1'],
            "des_trab_cot_av2" => $_POST['descripcion2'],
            "des_trab_cot_av3" => $_POST['descripcion3'],
            "des_trab_cot_av4" => $_POST['descripcion4'],
            "des_trab_cot_av5" => $_POST['descripcion5'],
            "des_trab_cot_av6" => $_POST['descripcion6'],
            "des_trab_cot_av7" => $_POST['descripcion7'],
            "precio_cot_av1" => $_POST['precio1'],
            "precio_cot_av2" => $_POST['precio2'],
            "precio_cot_av3" => $_POST['precio3'],
            "precio_cot_av4" => $_POST['precio4'],
            "precio_cot_av5" => $_POST['precio5'],
            "precio_cot_av6" => $_POST['precio6'],
            "precio_cot_av7" => $_POST['precio7'],
            "total_cot_av1" => $_POST['total1'],
            "total_cot_av2" => $_POST['total2'],
            "total_cot_av3" => $_POST['total3'],
            "total_cot_av4" => $_POST['total4'],
            "total_cot_av5" => $_POST['total5'],
            "total_cot_av6" => $_POST['total6'],
            "total_cot_av7" => $_POST['total7'],
            "sub_tot_cot_av" => $_POST['total'],
            "iva_cot_av" => $_POST['iva'],
            "total_neto_cot_av" => $_POST['totalNeto']
        );

        //$this->db->insert('cotizacion_avaluo_resultado',$insert);



            //print_r($data);
           $resultado = $this->valuaciones->actualizar_formato_valuaciones($data2,$updata,$id,$antes);

    }
```

mi `$data` es un array con 120 registros de 1 o 0 , los guardo en una tabla esos 120 registros mas los que estan en mi otro array `$comentarios`, mi otro array `$updata` se almacena en otra tabla.

Mi duda es como le puedo asignar la comulma(key) al array que viene en `$data`, esto es para hacer un update, ya lo hice con un insert y fue mas sencillo solo fue

```
insert into 'tabla'('columna_1'....'columna_120')value(".$data.")
```

y fue todo pero ahora en este caso es un update pero no se como hacerlo o si estoy mal en algo, lo corri asi pero me marca error 404 Not Found

Comment: Por lo que he entendido esos datos van a ser ingresados en alguna tabla de la base de datos. Cuando veo tantas columnas con el mismo nombre y un número incremental, me viene a la cabeza que el problema principal no es ese código, sino que tu tabla necesita urgentemente una *normalización*. ¿Por qué tienes tantas columnas que se repiten? ¿Por qué tu tabla funciona en horizontal y no en vertical? ¿Tienes libertad para cambiar el modelo de datos o debes ceñirte al que ya existe sin más remedio?

Comment: Son muchas repetidas porque es un formato de encuestas, en mi array ($data), vienen las respuestas de si eligio si o no y en form_obser_1 son los comentarios, podria decir por ejemplo por cada 12 preguntas tiene que haber un comentario de esas mismas y asi, los check son solo para seleccionar una parte de la imagen por eso esta tan asi, en el array ($updata), es otra tabla diferente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que comentas, creo que no te hace falta hacer nada en el update en lo relativo a tu otras variables $comentarios y $updata. Sólo necesitas hacer el update de los valores de $data, no?

Convendría que nos enseñaras como viene la variable $_POST['data']. Por lo que pones en tu comentario, tu variable viene así:

> ['1','0','0','1']

En ese caso tendrías que quitar los corchetes (tal y como lo haces en el código que nos muestras) y luego hacer un explode con el delimitador "\":

```
$data = str_replace("[","",$data);
$data = str_replace("]","",$data);
$data = explode(",", $data);
```

La query para updates debe tener la siguiente forma:

```
UPDATE tabla SET columna_1 = valor_1, columna_2 = valor_2, ...;
```

Me falta información sobre como es tu tabla (sobre todo los nombres de los campos), pero si es como la describes en el post, lo que haría en tu caso sería construir un string de la siguiente forma (doy por hecho que vas a actualizar todos los campos, por lo que comentas sobre los 120 valores):

```
$query = 'UPDATE tabla SET ';
for($i=0;$i<120;$i++){
    $query .= 'columna_'.($i+1).' = '.$data[$i].',';
}
$query = substr($query, 0, -1); //quitas la última coma.
```

Con lo que tu variable $query debería tener la forma:

> columna_1 = valor_1, columna_2 = valor_2, ... columna_120 = valor_120

Y ahora haces la query (PDO, secuencial,...como la hagas):

```
mysqli_query($conexion, $query);
```

NOTA: te lo he escrito todo "a pelo" (sin probar nada). Igual hay algun error tonto por ahí, pero la idea basicamente es esa.

NOTA2: lo que no me cuadra mucho (con la información que dispongo), es que te esté dando un error 404. Eso es página no encontrada, que no tiene nada que ver con algún problema en la sentencía de la SQL ni nada por el estilo. Si te sigue dando problemas, nos comentas.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: mi data viene asi : '1','0','0','1'.....etc. bueno loprobare aver que tal

Comment: Gracias amigo, me sirvió, nomas le cambie unas cosas y listo